# React Links inside Material-ui Grid stop working if the link is centered

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use material-ui's grid system but when I am using react-router-dom's Link component inside the grid it works unless the link is centered horizontally.  This is driving me cracy:

I am importing Grid and Link:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
```

The link here works fine:

```
<Grid container xs={12}>
  <Grid item xs={6} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Link to="#testimony">Testimony</Link>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But this, if all I do is change xs={6} to xs={7} does not work.  The the cursor doesn't turn to a pointer and clicking the link does nothing.

```
<Grid container xs={12}>
  <Grid item xs={7} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Link to="#testimony">Testimony</Link>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Comment: I created a codepen but there it works.  I don't know how to import material-ui into the codepen so I change the Link to an a tag and it works there but in my page, even if I change it to a a tag it doesn't work when centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this works but adding marginTop: 3rem made it work.  I also found out that having xs={12} on the Grid container tag is incorrect.

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item xs={7} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', 
      marginTop: '3rem', }}>
    <Link to="#testimony">Testimony</Link>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```